# How to use a TF metric with a model?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to compile a simple model and the following works just fine:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, I would like to use this metric: tf.metrics.precision_at_k and I am not sure how I can get it to work. It requires two arguments and that is causing an issue as I don't know how to pass predictions as an argument. I tried a

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=[tf.metrics.precision_at_k])
```

And certain variations but did not help.

Minimal working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(5, 5, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,  activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```